# Why using Magenta?

Tags: java, colors, background, tiles

I am interested in why magenta is used in many png tilesets as background?
Why isn't it simply transparent?
And also, how could one display just the image itself and show the magenta background as transparent in Java?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about magenta specifically, but it was common to use an easily-noticed color as the background in graphics files that used an indexed color model. The color index was then marked as the transparent color index. Picking a color like magenta (or pink, or something else bright) was intended to help the graphic artist notice areas that should be transparent that might have been missed.

Mostly this is a hold-over from earlier days when many popular graphics formats (and lower-end graphics tools) did not have a separate transparency channel.

Edit: As the comments so far point out, using an indexed color model without a separate transparency channel can greatly reduce the size of a graphics file. To support transparency in that case, it is very important to pick a transparent color that does not occur in the image itself. Magenta frequently fits the bill, which is probably why you are seeing it frequently in png tile sets.

Comment: I suppose, magenta it is used _chromakey_ cause it is rarely used in real images.

Comment: It will also depend on the type of palette begin used. It's common practice to reduce the size of the image, reducing the color palette is one way.  This makes the image faster to load and render and uses less memory.

Comment: Thank You all for the responses, I really don't know where I should go when I get questions. This is a great site with great people.